# Set difference is distributive over intersection proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm asked to prove the following:

$(A-B) ∩ C = (A ∩ C) - (B ∩ C)$ using the definitions of intersection and difference. So far I have:

$(A-B) ∩ C = \{(x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∉ B)\} ∧ \{(x ∈ C)\}$       "Defn of intersection and diff"

$ = \{(x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∈ C)\} ∧ \{(x ∉ B) ∧ (x ∈ C)\}$ "Logic"

And now I'm kinda stuck, is the top just equal to: $(A ∩ C) - (B ∩ C)$ and I'm done?

Answer (score 1):

$x\in (A-B)\cap C$

iff $x\in A, x\notin B$ and $x\in C$

iff $x\in A\cap C$ and $x\notin B\cap C$

iff $x\in (A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$.

So, $(A-B)\cap C=(A\cap C)-(B\cap C)$

Comment: I think this needs some more intermediate steps. How do you get $x\notin B\cap C$?

Comment: No need. Because if $x\in A, C$ and $x\notin B$ then it is clear that $x\in A\cap C$. And if $x\in B\cap C$ then it contradicts $x\notin B$. So clearly $x\notin B\cap C$.

Comment: OR since $x\notin B$ it is very clear that $x\notin B\cap C$ since $B\cap C \subset B$

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good expression to write:  $(A-B) ∩ C = {(x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∉ B)} ∧ {(x ∈ C)}$. You can write:

$$\color{red}{(A-B)\cap C}= \{x| (x\in (A-B) ∧ (x\in C)  \}=$$ 
$$\{x| (x\in A) ∧(x\notin B)∧ (x\in C)  \}=$$
$$\{x| \Big( (x\in A) ∧ (x\in C)\Big)∧\Big(x\notin B)∧ (x\in C)\Big) \}=$$
$$\{x| x\in \Big((A\cap C)-(B\cap C)\Big)\}= \color{red}{(A \cap C) - (B \cap C)}=\color{lime}{(A \cap C) - B}$$